# Sieve of Eratosthenes returning incorrect answers

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm a beginner trying to create a function to determine whether or not a value is prime or not.

```
def isPrime(number):
    marked = [] ## create empty list
    for i in xrange(2, number+1):
        if i not in marked: ## begin loop to remove multiples of i in list
            for j in xrange(i * i, number + 1, i):
                marked.append(j)
            if i == number: ## I'm assuming that if 
            ##the program made it here, i is not in marked.

print isPrime(7)
>>> True
print isPrime(10)
>>> None ## This should be False...ok so I tried to tinkering here.
```

So my attempt to fix that was to edit the last conditional to:

```
if i == number:
    return True
else: ## Begin new line of code to correct for false positive
    return False
```

This extra line messes up everything though because it now shows:

```
isPrime(7)
>>> False
```

**EDIT Turns out this method is entirely bad method to go. So according to a comment by Jean-Francois, this is an easier method to check for primes**

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n<2:
       return False  # handle special case
    sn = int(n**0.5)+1
    for i in range(2,sn):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

### Intuition:

Let's say we want to check if 61 is a prime.

- We know that anything below 2 can't be a prime so this code has a n<2
  to rule that out.
- We know that the square root of 61 is about 7.8,
  which also means that if 61 is a non-prime, we've ruled out the
  factor to be 8 or anything over 8.

So what's left to test is everything between 2 and 7. If everything between 2 and 7 to see if they're a factor of 61 and they still fail, that means we know this number is a prime.

Comment: Why are you assuming that the function ever reaches `i == number` for a composite `i`?

Comment: Also, this is an extremely inefficient way to mark numbers.

Comment: Can you advise on a better way for a beginner? I also added at the end the test case where i == 7.

Comment: I said *composite* `i`. Also, a list of booleans representing whether the corresponding number is marked or not marked is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this even if this is not really new stuff. It answers the question, gives 2 ways of working and is tested and in python. Should be ontopic.

First, computing the sieve each time is very unefficient to test for one number.
If you have a lot of numbers to test, then that's the way.
A working version (python 2 & 3 compatible), adapted by me from some [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/) solution

```
def primes(n):
    """Generate a list of the prime numbers [2, 3, ... m] where
    m is the largest prime <= n."""
    n += 1
    sieve = list(range(n))
    sieve[:2] = [0, 0]
    for i in range(2, int(n**0.5)+1):
        if sieve[i]:
            for j in range(i**2, n, i):
                sieve[j] = 0
    # Filter out the composites, which have been replaced by 0's
    return [p for p in sieve if p]
```

testing:

```
print(primes(100))
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

To test for a specific number, do this instead

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n<2:
       return False  # handle special case
    sn = int(n**0.5)+1  # +1 because of perfect squares like 49
    for i in range(2,sn):
        if n%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I added n>=2 to your code to make it pass is_prime(0) by the way.

Comment: You're right. I just wrote it, so I forgot the corner cases.

Comment: I've spent this entire time trying to ask why this is the answer but I..figured it out myself. So for future readers - here's the intuition. 

Let's say we want to check if 61 is a prime. x =< 2 are all non-primes so no need to check for that. Square root of 61 is about 7.8. So there's no need to check if this number is a factor of 8, since that clearly exceeds 61. So this also checks the numbers between 2 to 7 to see if that is a factor of 61. If all factors between 2 to 7 fail, then the number is a prime. Whew. Let me know if there's anything wrong with my thought process.

Comment: That's right. Be careful with the upper boundary. the `+1` is really needed in cases of perfect squares, else it would tell that 49 is prime.